# How to sort this array in numeric order using php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort a list of files by their filename.

This is my array:

```
Array
(
    [5] => 
    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 194
            [filename] => 1.2 Organogram company BV.pptx
            [name] => undefined
            [path] => /home/website/public_html/fileupload/company/organisatie/
            [cat_id] => 297
            [error] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 195
            [filename] => 1.2 VOL VCA R. company 13-12-2024.docx
            [name] => undefined
            [path] => /home/website/public_html/fileupload/company/organisatie/
            [cat_id] => 297
            [error] => 0
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 196
            [filename] => 1.2 MVK- diploma 2016 Piet Schipaanboord.jpg
            [name] => undefined
            [path] => /home/website/public_html/fileupload/company/organisatie/
            [cat_id] => 297
            [error] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 200
            [filename] => 1.1 Beleidsverklaring 20-09-2018.docx
            [name] => undefined
            [path] => /home/website/public_html/fileupload/company/organisatie/
            [cat_id] => 297
            [error] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 201
            [filename] => 1.2 Functieomschrijving VGM-functionaris.docx
            [name] => undefined
            [path] => /home/website/public_html/fileupload/company/organisatie/
            [cat_id] => 297
            [error] => 0
        )

)
```

As you can see it is now sorted like:

```
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.1
1.2
```

How can I sort this the correct way? Like this:

```
1.1
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
```

I've tried `asort` like this:

```
$getfiles = "SELECT * FROM files1 WHERE cat_id = 20";
$getfilescon = $conn->query($getfiles);
while($getfiles[] = $getfilescon->fetch_assoc());
asort($getfiles, $getfiles['filename']);
```

Or like this:

```
asort($getfiles['filename']);
```

Or this:

```
asort($getfiles[]['filename']);
```

But nothing is giving the desired result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and create your own sorting priority.
It should look something like this.

```
function customSort($a, $b) {
    if ($a['filename'] == $b['filename']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['filename'] < $b['filename']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($array, "customSort");
```

Or if you use PHP 7+

```
usort($array, function (array $a, array $b) {
    return $a['filename'] <=> $b['filename'];
});
```

Comment: Cheers, bear in mind though that 1.2 is going to be ranked before 1.10, since the function is only comparing the names as string. If you need to compare them as numeric values you will need to split the data and parse them in a bit more complex function.

Comment: Yeah makes sense, but there probably won't be more than a few documents on every page so I should be good.